# Python - How to count number of Matplotlib Contours in image?

Tags: python, matplotlib

**What I'm trying to do:**
Write a program that counts the number of Matplotlib contours in a series of plots, adds them up, and displays the total number of contours.

**What I've done so far:**
I have created plots of my desired variable with contours that correspond to a given threshold, like so: [image: example of thresholded contour image]

I have a bunch of these plots that show other regions with contours.

**What I've tried:**
I looked at [this website](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-count-the-number-of-objects-in-an-image-Python-OpenCV.php) for guidance. I attempted to use cv2 to count the number of contours, but it gives me this error: [image: error message]

Am I going about this the wrong way? I'm not sure if cv2 is what I'm supposed to be using, and I'm wondering if matplotlib has something native to it that will help with this. I wasn't able to find anything when I Google'd it, which is why I'm asking here.

Here's the code that produces the plots with contours:

```
threshVertVeloLL = vertVeloLLComp > 9

res = '1km'
buffer = '5km'
buffer_px = int((units(buffer) / units(res)).m)
bufferedVV = binary_dilation(threshVertVeloLL.values, footprint=disk(buffer_px))

labeled_image, _ = label(bufferedVV, np.ones((3,3), dtype=int))
remove_small_objects(labeled_image, min_size=buffer_px * 3, connectivity=2)

subsets_VV = []
for region in regionprops(labeled_image):
    subsets_VV.append(vertVeloLLComp.isel(
        yh=slice(region.bbox[0], region.bbox[2]),
        xh=slice(region.bbox[1], region.bbox[3])
    ))
    
plt.imshow(labeled_image)

images = []

for subset_VV in subsets_VV:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10,10))
    subset_VV.plot(ax=ax, cmap=get_cmap('coolwarm'))
    img = plt.contour(subset_VV.metpy.x, subset_VV.metpy.y, subset_VV, levels=[10.])
    '''How do I count number of contours in each image?'''
#    x_min = subset_VV['xh'].min().item()
#    x_max = subset_VV['xh'].max().item()
#    y_min = subset_VV['yh'].min().item()
#    y_max = subset_VV['yh'].max().item()
    #[0.15, 0.15, 0.25, 0.25]
#    ax_inset = fig.add_axes(
#        [0.15, 0.15, 0.25, 0.25])
#    vertVeloLLComp.plot(ax=ax_inset)
#    ax_inset.plot(
#        [x_min, x_max, x_max, x_min, x_min],
#        [y_min, y_min, y_max, y_max, y_min])
#    ax_inset.set_axis_off()
     images.append(img)
     plt.show()
```

What should I do? In addition, is there matplotlib functionality that would calculate the area of each contour, as well as calculating the average value of the variable in each contour? I really appreciate the help! Apologies if I asked too much, and let me know if I can provide any more information! Thank you!

**EDIT:**
Here's the original image as requested by Jeru Luke
[image: Original image]

And here's the OpenCV code I wrote:

```
for image in images:
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    edges= cv2.Canny(gray, 50,200)

    contours, hierarchy= cv2.findContours(edges.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

Comment: I am pretty sure `img.collections` is a list of all the contours, so `len(img.collections)` will tell you how many contours there are.  Unfortunately you have not provided a self contained example so I can't test that for you, but hopefully you can figure it out.

Comment: OpenCV has built-in functions to meet your requirements. Please share your original image. Also share the OpenCV code to point out the error

Comment: @JeruLuke I updated my question at the end with my original image and OpenCV code.

Comment: @JodyKlymak I tried print(len(img.collections)) in my for loop, but it printed out a length of 1 for each image, which is not correct. How can I provide a self-contained example for you? I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand what that would entail. I would be happy to provide it though!

Comment: Please see http://sscce.org/